# Can I have LAMP on the bench / in the field?

Tags: dna, bacteriology, assay-development

I am interested in LAMP for detecting small amounts of DNA (loop-mediated isothermal amplification and yes, I know the initials don't match).

I am trying to figure out exactly how clean/(sterile?) everything needs to be.

On one hand:
-papers repeatedly stress that the assay is very sensitive and to avoid contamination
-these very nice guidelines (https://www.rtlamp.org/get-started/rt-lamp-open-access/) include the requirement for a PCR hood. I think this website is otherwise reasonable and thorough as it mentioned that HNB dye should be in its trisodium form (which most papers do not mention)

On the other hand:
-I'll be working with DNA, not RNA; less fragile
-the point of LAMP is supposed to be that it requires more basic equipment than PCR. If it still requires a clean bench, that sort of flies out of the window.
-a quick search for 'field LAMP amplification' found a publication (https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2022/ew/d2ew00433j - 'In-field LAMP assay for rapid detection of human faecal contamination in environmental water'). But I don't have enough experience in the field to tell whether this is a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't do chemistry or bench work, so I can't speak to conditions required for LAMP in the lab. However, I know people who have developed a portable LAMP set-up that works in the field. It's still something of a prototype, with testing going on, but this paper provides you some idea. The process doesn't require very stringent cleaning. So to answer your question, yes, you can use LAMP in the field. I'd assume in the lab too, since the field set-up is portable and I've seen them use the unit in the lab.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0956566320305820

Comment: Hello. Thank you. The paper that you linked is not really about LAMP - maybe you meant one of the references in it, or something else altogether? If you can adjust that, I will accept the answer.

Comment: I changed the reference. The Introduction includes multiple references to LAMP in the field.